# Does Angular handle interpolation and one way binding the same way?

Tags: angular, interpolation

I am currently creating an application that frequently changes the text and images on a page. Chrome consumes almost the whole cpu after a few hours of running. Please note that it is not an option to just restart the browser if this problem arises.

I have now tried to disable the UI rendering and just receiving data updates from the server and the problem seems to be gone.

```html
<img class="icon" src="{{myIcon1}}"/>
<img class="icon" [src]="myIcon2"/>
```

Does Angular update only the "src" attribute for the first line as it would for the second or does it always create a complete new instance of the whole component template if "myIcon1" changes?

Comment: How many images do you have on the page which are being updated?

Comment: it seems what you are really looking for is `Angular onPush Change Detection Strategy`

Comment: read this article : https://medium.com/@bencabanes/angular-change-detection-strategy-an-introduction-819aaa7204e7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Interpolation and data binding are alternate to each other. But the key difference between them is that if we can concatenate string in interpolation case.
`myIcon1 = "sample.jpg";
<img class="icon" src="https://www.sample/{{myIcon1}}"/>`

Property Binding is used to set an element property to a non-string data value

```
    <button [disabled]='isDisable'>Click Me</button>
```

Changing disable property will disable/enable button accordingly.
But if we use

```
    <button disabled='{{isDisable}}'>Click Me</button>
```

Button will always be disable irrespective of isDisable Property

For more reference https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#!#interpolation

Answer (score 0):

I think it updates the virtual DOM and in return, it renders the whole interface from scratch. But with Angular 8 they are implementing an incremental DOM. I've read about it on this site.

https://blog.nrwl.io/understanding-angular-ivy-incremental-dom-and-virtual-dom-243be844bf36